# How do I draw a square with rounded corners in Adobe Flash CS6?

Tags: adobe-flash, drawing

I can't find any options for rounded corners in the draw palette in Flash CS6 and Google is not returning any answers. This seems like it should be so simply to do. I want to use the palette to draw a rectangle with rounded corners WITHOUT using actionscript. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/animation-and-3d/9780133052718/4dot-modifying-simple-graphics/ch04lev1sec9

> With Flash’s rectangle- and oval-primitive tools, you create shapes
>   with paths defined by a set of properties specific to that shape. You
>   can’t change the outline of a primitive-shape freely the way you can
>   reshape the outline of a merge-shape or drawing-object. You can change
>   the primitive’s defining properties by dragging control points in the
>   shape or by setting new values in the Property inspector.

The rectangle-primitive has two control points for the corner radius of each corner. When the corner radius is set to 0, the corner is a sharp 90-degree angle, and the control points sit directly on top of one another.

- Position the pointer over one of the control points. The pointer becomes a solid arrowhead.
- To modify the shape, do one of the following:
  • To increase the radius (make the corner more rounded), drag the point inward.
  • To decrease the radius (make the corner less rounded), drag the point outward.
- As the corner radius increases, two control points appear at the end of the arc defining the corner. Drag inward to round the corner more; drag outward to round it less.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. The problem is that I can't find that button in CS6. Do you know where it is in CS6?

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: click and hold on the rectangle tool it should appear just below

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rectangle Primitive Tool instead of the Rectangle Tool

Comment: This is the same answer @Yisela gave month ago?